# "scroll" event listener not triggering

Tags: javascript, html, events, event-handling, dom-events

I'm currently working on a vanilla JS plugin, and I need to update a value on scroll, so I attached an event listener to the document to trigger a function that should update the aforementioned value.

Thing is, it works on document load but not on scroll. It's as if the scroll event isn't working at all.

Currently, my JS part looks something like this:

```
var currentPosition = 0;

var updatePosition = function() {
  currentPosition = document.body.scrollTop;
  document.getElementById('indicator').textContent = currentPosition;
};

document.addEventListener('scroll', updatePosition());
```

Here's a fiddle to make it a bit more clear: **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/1vqjanLm/1/)**

I tried attaching the event listener on both the body and the window, it makes no difference whatsoever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are directly invoking a function using `updatePosition()`, and that is because you function fire at page start, you must attach and handler using only the function name `updatePosition`.

Code:

```
document.addEventListener('scroll', updatePosition);
                                                  |-- no () here
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/dyy6z35s/

Comment: Thanks a bunch. Correct, and concise!

Answer (score 0):

```
var currentPosition = 0;

var updatePosition = function() {
  currentPosition = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;      
  document.getElementById('indicator').textContent = currentPosition;    
};

document.addEventListener('scroll', updatePosition);
```

http://jsbin.com/seqecezecu/1/edit?js,console,output